# How to convert Vue 2 web site to PWA wab app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, progressive-web-apps

I have checked PWA function when use vue 3 but there aren't in vue 2.
so if you have good idea to convert from vue 2 project to pwa, please share.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer for my question. I will share it for all developers.

First, I have done follow this this
[vue/cli-plugin-pwa](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html#example-configuration)

Second:
make registerServiceWorker.js file with this code:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready () {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n'
      )
    },
    registered () {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
    },
    cached () {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
    },
    updatefound () {
      console.log('New content is downloading.')
    },
    updated () {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
    },
    offline () {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
    },
    error (error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    }
  })
}
```

Third:
make service-worker.js:

```
// inside src/service-worker.js 

// define a prefix for your cache names. It is recommended to use your project name
workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({prefix:  "simple-vue-project"});

// Start of Precaching##########################
// __precacheManifest is the list of resources you want to precache. This list will be generated and imported automatically by workbox during build time
self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
// End of Precaching############################

// Start of CachFirst Strategy##################
// all the api request which matchs the following pattern will use CacheFirst strategy for caching
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
/http:\/\/get\.geojs\.io\/v1\/ip\/country\.json/,
new  workbox.strategies.CacheFirst()
);
// End of CachFirst Strategy####################
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a Vue.js plugin, [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html).
if not :
Create a services worker, you can introduce to it [here](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker)
add webmanifest or manifest.json of your choice, read [here](https://web.dev/add-manifest/)

Add express to your project as depencency

create server.js like file, and serve the built Vue App from the server with express

```
// server.js ex:
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/ping', function (req, res) {
  return res.send('ping');
});
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html')); //serving build folder
});
app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern `@vue/cli` provides you the option to turn on PWA while scaffolding both Vue 2 as well as Vue 3 projects. Check out this [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create).

If you have already created the project, [CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#using-the-gui) offers a new functionality called Vue UI. Simply type `vue ui` in the cmd and it should open up Vue UI where you can reconfigure your project using graphical interface.

If you are interested in learning Vue JS check out these courses - [Complete Vue JS Course](https://www.udemy.com/course/vuejs-complete-course-plus-guide/?referralCode=93BDA4A1FE3F73C37CD2), [Vue 3 Essentials](https://www.eduonix.com/vue-3-essentials?coupon_code=HAPPYLEARNING)